# embedding as3 fonts into a swf without flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way to create embedded "pure as3" swf fonts using compc (without the flex framework integration)?  If I embed a font like this in my as3:

```
package fonts
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.Font;

public class Helvetica extends Sprite
{

    [Embed(source='Helvetica.otf', fontName='Helvetica')]

    public static var Helvetica :Class;

    Font.registerFont( Helvetica  );

}
}
```

using compc.exe -compiler.keep-generated-actionscript=true

I see flex makes some boilerplate as3 code including things like this:

```
import mx.core.IFlexModule;
import mx.core.IFlexModuleFactory;
import mx.core.EmbeddedFontRegistry;
```

which prevents me from using the embedded font in "pure as3" projects.  Is there a way to get flex-free fonts using compc?

I am hoping there is an [easy solution like this one](http://blog.brokenfunction.com/2009/03/16/how-to-remove-flex-libraries-completely-from-your-as3-project/) for Bitmap Assets.

Comment: Did you apply the method described in the article following your link? It might work for you too. I'm just sayin'...

Comment: The fonts are a bit more complicated.  Their boilerplate attempts to register with  the 'mx.core::IEmbeddedFontRegistry' http://forums.adobe.com/message/1885964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i think the method disrribed should work anyhow ... you just got to replace few more classes ... probably `EmbeddedFontRegistry`, so it won't have any dependancies ... just stuff in an empty method ...

greetz

back2dos